# Bootstrap modal displaying wrong format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap modal in my asp.net application, but it is not displaying correct.

The bootstrap:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="modal fade" id="defaultErrors" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">X</button>
                    <h4 id="myModalLabel1" class="modal-title"><strong>Error!</strong></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                        <p id="msgError"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I call it using JQuery:

```
$("#msgError").html("Error custom message.");
    $("#defaultErrors").modal();
```

The result is a ugly modal:
[image]

I'm using bootstrap bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: If the modal opens, bootstrap.js is probably loaded. At first glance your template seems fine for v3.3. Are you sure the Bootstrap CSS file is loaded? Could you try debugging by putting a simple Bootstrap element in the modal body and then can check if it's styled from Bootstrap styles? If not we'll know the modal content doesn't see the Bootstrap CSS file.

Comment: Hum... bootstrap.min.css is loading, but its styles is not working.

Comment: Can you check if some other style is overriding the bootstrap styles?

Comment: I include the bootstrap.min.css before the JS files and it worked like a champ. Any reason why?

Comment: In this fiddle the code you've supplied runs just fine, you must have some custom CSS that's overriding bootstraps styles.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/42509/